# Are there any official or fanmade character sheets for Diaspora?

Tags: character-sheets, diaspora

I'm planning a game of Diaspora that I will be hosting at a convention, and I'm trying to get some fancy looking character sheets for the players. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find any.

Searching the web brings up various links, but they are all dead. I looked at the Fate Core character sheets, since the games is based on that, but they won't work, because the Diaspora stats are different.

Do any web sources with either the official (preferred) or a fanmade character sheet still exist? Or does anyone happen to have any old ones around that they can share?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a little googling...

The "Diaspora SRD" page [here](http://www.vsca.ca/Diaspora/diaspora-srd.html), and general searching, suggests that www.phreeow.net/Diaspora/ should be where the official Diaspora sheets might be found, but as you note this no longer seems to have the character sheet available.

Luckily we can just use archive.org's [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org) to view archived versions of the content. The most recent copy of this resource was made in [February](https://web.archive.org/web/20180213161047/www.phreeow.net/Diaspora/); even then many of the links don't seem to be working or at least weren't archived, but it does have a working copy of the [character sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20170614072117/http://www.phreeow.net/Diaspora/Diaspora%20character%20sheet.pdf) (and even the folding [convention version](https://web.archive.org/web/20180213161047/www.phreeow.net/Diaspora/Diaspora%20character%20sheet%20con.pdf)).

If you found other links you want to investigate that no longer work, you could consider plugging them into the Wayback Machine and seeing if you get lucky.

Comment: Awesome! I tried using the Wayback Machine, but I couldn't get it work properly.